# how to create columns of array

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays, bordermatrix

I use the following code to generate this:

```
\begin{center}
2 Iteración\\
Fila $S_{1}$
\end{center}
\small
\[\begin{array}{crl}
\kbordermatrix{\mbox{ }&
 & & & & & & \\
 Fila Vieja & 0 & 2  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &18        \\  
   C. Pivote & 2 & 2  & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &2\\   
   Nueva F. Pivote & 0 & 1  & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 8       \\\cline{2-8} 
   Nueva Fila & 0 & 0  & 1/3 & 1 & 0 & -2/3 & 2      \\   
} 
\end{array}\]

  \begin{center}
Fila $S_{2}$
\end{center}
\small
\[\begin{array}{crl}
\kbordermatrix{\mbox{ }&
 & & & & & & \\
 Fila Vieja & 0 & 2  & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 42       \\  
   C. Pivote & 2 & 2  & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &2\\   
   Nueva F. Pivote & 0 & 1  & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 8       \\\cline{2-8} 
   Nueva Fila & 0 & 0  & 7/3 & 0 & 1 & -2/3 & 26      \\   
} 
\end{array}\]
  \begin{center}
Fila $Z$
\end{center}
\small
\[\begin{array}{crl}
\kbordermatrix{\mbox{ }&
 & & & & & & \\
 Fila Vieja & 1 & -3  & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0       \\  
   C. Pivote & -3 & -3  & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 & -3\\   
   Nueva F. Pivote & 0 & 1  & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 8       \\\cline{2-8} 
   Nueva Fila & 1 & 0  & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 24      \\   
} 
\end{array}\]
```

[image: image result]

My question is how could I do this in multiple columns?

I'm sorry, I'm having some exercises the simplex method to latex, but I see that you are spreading far, so I started to investigate how to place this in 3 columns thing I could not do.

Example
[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package which helps you put anything you like in two (or more) columns.  E.g.

```
...
\usepackage{multicol}
...
\begin{multicols}{2}
...
\end{multicols}
...
```

You can use `\columnbreak` if you want to break your text manually.